# SVM hyperplane equation

Tags: svm, notation

I am trying to understand the hyperplane of the SVM algorithm. My problem is that different sources state different equations.

Which equation is the right one and if both are right, why?

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine):    $w\cdot x-b = 0.$
- [Intelligent Data Analysis and Probabilistic Inference notes](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~dfg/ProbabilisticInference/IDAPILecture18.pdf):  $ w\cdot x+b = 0.$

Furthermore, I thought the normal form of a plane looks like this:

$$ w\cdot x + w\cdot a = 0.$$

Comment: They are equivalent. The interpretation of $b$ in the first equation is the same as $-b$ in the second equation.

Comment: Just to get it right. That means that the dot product of w⋅a of the third equation equals +/-b? where b is the shift of the plane?

Comment: Indeed, note that this is related to the different parameterisations of the [line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Linear_equations_in_two_variables)/plane equations (point-slope, two points, slope-intercept ...)